# BackUp БД postgresql через pg_dump не работает при вызове команды из Spring

Tags: java, база-данных, postgresql, spring, kotlin

**Дано:**

БД `postgresql` на `Mac`. В ней есть данные и я могу сделать `BackUp` из консоли вызвав `/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_dump -U db_user_name -w -c -f my_db_name.sql my_db_name`, что создаст файл `my_db_name.sql` в папке где я вызываю команду.

**Задача:**

Настроить периодический `BackUp` БД через `Spring`.

**Проблема:**

При вызове вышеуказанного скрипта программно получаю ошибку `Файл не найден`

**Вопрос:**

Как же это реализовать? Кажется, проблема в правах доступа к файлам/папкам, но непонятно какая именно и как узнать конкретно.

**Пробовал:**

Пробовал указывать абсолютный путь типа `{ПУТЬ_К_ПРОЕКТУ_СПРИНГА}/my_db_name.sql` или `/Users/myusername/my_db_name.sql` - не помогает.

**Код:**

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
fun backUpDb() {
    val executeCmd = "/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_dump -U $dbUserName -w -c -f $database.sql $database"

    val runtimeProcess: Process
    try {
        val pb = ProcessBuilder(executeCmd)
        pb.redirectOutput(Redirect.INHERIT)
        pb.redirectError(Redirect.INHERIT)
        runtimeProcess = pb.start()
        val processComplete = runtimeProcess.waitFor()

        if (processComplete == 0) {
            println("Backup created successfully")
        } else {
            println("Could not create the backup")
        }
    } catch (ex: Exception) {
        ex.printStackTrace()
    }
}
```

**Лог:**

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/Library/PostgreSQL/10/bin/pg_dump -U db_user_name -w -c -f my_db_name.sql my_db_name": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at ru.scp.quiz.service.quiz.QuizServiceImpl.backUpDb(QuizServiceImpl.kt:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в том, что команда в одной строке не распознаётся и надо составлять массив из каждой её части и тогда оно работает. Т.е. надо команду в массив превратить при передаче `ProcessBuilder`-у:

```
val pb = ProcessBuilder(executeCmd.split(" "))
```

Comment: А вообще гиблое это дело - из спринга это делать. Лучше пусть ОС это сама делает вот так: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/907601/17609