# Бэкап MySQL базы через Java приложение

Tags: java, mysql

Делаю бэкапы базы данный MySQL в Java приложении.
Вот код:

```
try {            
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p " + dbPass;
executeCmd += " --all-databases > " + savePath;
System.out.println(executeCmd);
Process proc = rt.exec(executeCmd);
InputStream stderr = proc.getErrorStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stderr);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
System.out.println("<ERROR>");
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(line);
System.out.println("</ERROR>");
int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
System.out.println("Process exitValue: " + exitVal);
}
    catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

В ответ получаю `exitValue: 1`.
Если скопировать вывод `System.out.pritln(executecmd);` в cmd все работает прекрасно. Может кто-то сказать, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте тут посмотреть как можно иначе запустить команду с выводом в консоль подробных результатов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/828996/17609

Comment: проблема в том, что мне нечего выводить в консоль. Ошибок нет. Команда выполняемая через cmd не дает ошибок/варнингов. Таже команда через Java просто показывает, что она не выполнилась. опять же без варнингов или ошибок.

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `--verbose` в команду для вывода чего-нибудь в консоль

Answer (score 1):

Проблем здесь:

```
String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p " + dbPass;
executeCmd += " --all-databases > " + savePath;
```

Работает в таком виде:

```
String executeCmd = "mysqldump.exe -u " + dbUser + " -p" + dbPass+" dbName -r " + savePath;
```

Чем-то Java не устраивало -all-databases и > вместо -r.