# Как на Linux (Debian/Ubuntu) настроить автоматические BackUp БД Postgresql

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postgresql, cron, crontab

**Дано:**

Установлен `Postgresql`. В нём есть БД.

**Задача:**

По расписанию делать бэкап.

**Вопрос:**

Как это сделать на `Linux` силами ОС?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Создаём папки для бэкапов и логов:

   `/data/dbBackup/myDbName/logs` силами `ftp` клиента или вручную, через консоль.
2. Устанавливаем редактор текстовых файлов `nano`, если его нет в системе:

   `apt-get install nano`
3. Запускаем `crontab` программу для редактирования списка задач `cron`-а, используя `nano`:

   `EDITOR=nano crontab -e`
4. Создаём задачу для `cron` путём добавления команды к исполнению по расписанию. В данном случае - раз в минуту. `/usr/bin/pg_dump` - путь к метоположению программы `pg_dump`, которая, собственно и делает бэкап. `myDbName` - имя базы данных для которой надо сделать бэкап. `>> /d
   ata/dbBackup/myDbName/logs/dbBackup.log 2>&1` - нужно для получения логов выполнения задачи. Например, если у вас нет каких-то прав, папки не созданы, пароль к БД у юзера, запускающего программу бэкапов неверен или ещё что - сообщение об ошибке запишется в файл `/d
   ata/dbBackup/myDbName/logs/dbBackup.log`. `$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M-\%S)` - нужно для создания файла, в имени которого будет дата его создания.

   `* * * * * /usr/bin/pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost -w -c -f /data/dbBackup/myDbName/myDbName_$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d-\%H-\%M-\%S).sql myDbName >> /data/dbBackup/myDbName/logs/dbBackup.log 2>&1`
5. Чтобы сохранить изменения в `crontab` надо:

   `Ctrl`+`X` чтобы выйти, `Y` чтобы подтвердить сохранение изменений, `Enter` чтобы подтвердить в какой файл сохранить.

---

Чтобы следить в реальном времени за запуском задач `cron`-а:

`tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON`

Comment: Ежеминутный бекап? не перебор ли?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, ну так это же HelloWorld бэкап, для примера)